# Loading jSON data partially when it's necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a infinite slider. Idea is simple:

Let's assume we have 10 elements in jSON array.

We load 3 elements first to show, after some time slider goes down, and we load 4th element to show it, removing 1st with .remove() method. Then we go futher, and we load 5th element, and delete 2nd and so on. When we reach 10th element, we load 1st element and delete 8th, so it loops. 1->2->3->...->10->1->2->...

And now I need some help with writing that code. I want to get a functions which I can put in setInterval(). jSON code is following:

```
{"comments":
[
    {
        "comment_body":"To jest pierwszy komentarz.",
        "comment_user":"Jan Kowalski",
        "comment_avatar":"https:\/\/img.com\/img.png",
        "comment_from":"FB",
        "comment_url":"https:\/\/facebook.com\/121234"
    },
    {
        "comment_body":"To jest drugi komentarz.",
        "comment_user":"Jan Kupka",
        "comment_avatar":"https:\/\/img.com\/img.png",
        "comment_from":"TW",
        "comment_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/121234"
    },
    {   "comment_body":"A to jest trzeci komentarz.",
        "comment_user":"Jan Kowalski",
        "comment_avatar":"https:\/\/img.com\/img.png",
        "comment_from":"FB",
        "comment_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/121234"
    },
    {   "comment_body":"Kolejny komentarz.",
        "comment_user":"Jan Kucharski",
        "comment_avatar":"https:\/\/img.com\/img.png",
        "comment_from":"TW",
        "comment_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/121234"
    }
]
}
```

And the function for getting it:

```
$.getJSON("js/comments.js", function(data) {

    $.each(data.comments, function(i, data) {

        var $comment_div = "<div class='comment'><p class='comment-text'>"+data.comment_body+"</p><img class='comment-photo' src='"+data.comment_url+"'/><a rel='"+data.comment_from+"' class='name' href='"+data.comment_url+"'>"+data.comment_user+" via <i class='fa'></i></a></div>";

        $($comment_div).appendTo('#comments-content');

    });
});
```

This code loads entire content of jSON file and shows it on the site. But I want to achieve what I wrote above, but I have no idea how to do that.

I hope you can help me with that, thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't you use a PHP script to provide the json? then you can control the number of entries on the json response.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading JSON" ? Doing multiple ajax requests will make you waste a lot more time than loading all the JSON items at once (assuming there is a reasonable amount of them) than loading them one by one.

Comment: Problem is I have to avoid PHP in that case. It's all about having only 3 records visible and then just loading next item from array, and if there is no such item, loading 1st and so on.

Comment: @Virus721 Yes, but I don't know how to form my question. I need to load all data at once, but to insert into dom only some of them at a time.

Comment: See my answer. Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that in your comment.js you have something like this

```
var comments = {"comments" : [....]};
var count = 3;
```

then you need to add

```
return comments["comments"].slice(begin, begin + count);
```

and your getting function becomes, where **start** changes after each call

```
$.getJSON("js/comments.js", {begin: start}, function(data) {
```

UPD.

```
var resComments = comments["comments"].slice(begin, begin + count);
return JSON.stringify({"comments" : resComments});
```

Comment: I tried to make comments.js like that, but then it just doen't load data from it.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really get it. All I need is to call proper array item from json code and add it to the end, and then remove the 1st item from displayed 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
var comments = yourJSON.comments;
var index = 0;
var comments.length; // Not sure if that exists but you'll figure it out.

var inter = setInterval( function() { // No need to save return value if it never stops.

   // Do stuff using comments [i]

   index  = (index + 1) % max;

}, 5000 );
```